# How many folds are used, cross validation with rpart printcp

Tags: cart

I am using rpart to generate a decision tree and the printcp function (from the rpart package) to cross-validate.

I have read the documentation and help pages, however I cannot find how many folds the printcp function is using when calculating the cross-validation error.